# Update Hour time(T) in mongoDB without changing date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have number of documents with userId and time. I want to update hour time in batchTimings array without changing Date

I have userId and time

| userID | New Start Time | New End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2076668 | 10:00 AM | 2:00 PM |
| 2032172 | 10:00 AM | 2:00 PM |
| 2070442 | 2:00 PM | 6:00 PM |
| 2030321 | 3:00 PM | 5:00 PM |

```
//1 
{
"userId" : NumberLong(2076055),
    "batchTimings" : [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2022-03-23T11:00:00.000Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2022-03-23T15:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

// 2
 {
"userId" : NumberLong(2076668),
    "batchTimings" : [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2022-03-24T05:00:00.000Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2022-03-24T07:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

// 3
{
"userId" : NumberLong(2070442),
    "batchTimings" : [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2022-03-15T09:00:00.000Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2022-03-15T11:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
 }

// 4 
 {
"userId" : NumberLong(2032172),
    "batchTimings" : [
        {
            "start": ISODate("2022-03-09T04:30:00.000Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2022-03-09T06:30:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
 }
```

I have written script for updation for 2 documents. But for large(200-300).This is not possible.So i need script which match batchId and updated time as per excel sheet.

```
var batch = [
{ "userId": 2076055, "batchstarttime": ISODate("2022-03-23T05:30:00Z"), "batchendtime": ISODate("2022-06-23T09:30:00Z") },
{ "userId": 2076076, "batchstarttime": ISODate("2022-01-23T04:30:00Z"), "batchendtime": ISODate("2022-03-25T09:30:00Z") },]

batch.forEach(x => {
db.batch.update({
    "userId": x["userId"]
}, {
    $set: {
        "batchTimings.0.start": x["batchstarttime"],
        "batchTimings.0.end": x["batchendtime"]
    }})
})
```

Comment: Is `"batchTimings"` always an array with a single object element?  If so, why is it an array?  If not, how will you identify which array element to update?

Comment: Yes batchTimings its an array. Its  already there with single object inside DB for all userId's

Comment: So where do these time updates come from?  I.e., why can't a script read, say, the update file and apply the updates to the DB?

Comment: I just want to update batchTimings start time and end time that's it. Data is already there that's what i am saying just update hour with same date

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set, and use date operators to calculate new datetime from existing datetime: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators

Comment: Aggregate function just returns the value and set i have already used in my script as you can see to update 2 documents. But what i need is a script which matches the particular userId and updates hour without altering the existing date

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, it's not to aggregate but to use the pipeline in update operations: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: These Updates with Aggregation Pipeline are used when you have logic or particular sum or subtraction, But for my problem the matching element should be changed as per given sheet.

Comment: I think you get it wrong. The pipeline in updates just unlocks pipeline expressions to apply your logic to manipulate data. In your case - split datetime to components, set time, compile datetime back from components and update the field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247342/discussion-between-abhishek-k-v-and-alex-blex).

Answer (score 0):

Below are four ways you could `update` the times and keep the dates of your `"batchTimings"`.  Each `"start"`/`"end"` shows a different way.

N.B.: As stated by the OP, `"batchTimings"` is an array with a single object element.  These update pipelines depend on that.  If `"batchTimings"` grows, some additional logic will be needed to select the appropriate array element.

This update pipeline shows two ways (`"$dateFromParts"` & `"$dateTrunc"`/`"$dateAdd"`).

```js
db.collection.update({
  "userId": NumberLong(2076668)
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "batchTimings.start": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "startParts": {
              "$dateToParts": {
                "date": {"$first": "$batchTimings.start"}
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": "$$startParts.year",
              "month": "$$startParts.month",
              "day": "$$startParts.day",
              // enter start hour here
              "hour": 10
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "batchTimings.end": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "endTrunc": {
              "$dateTrunc": {
                "date": {"$first": "$batchTimings.end"},
                "unit": "day"
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$dateAdd": {
              "startDate": "$$endTrunc",
              "unit": "hour",
              // enter end hour here
              "amount": 14
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iMDd1JP7fwX).

Here are two more ways (`"$dateFromString"`/`"$replaceOne"`/`"$regexFind"` & `"$dateTrunc"`/`"$add"`).

```js
db.collection.update({
  "userId": NumberLong(2070442)
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "batchTimings.start": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "startString": {
              "$dateToString": {
                "date": {"$first": "$batchTimings.start"}
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": {
                "$replaceOne": {
                  "input": "$$startString",
                  "find": {
                    "$getField": {
                      "field": "match",
                      "input": {
                        "$regexFind": {
                          "input": "$$startString",
                          "regex": "T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  // enter start time here
                  "replacement": "T14:00:00"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "batchTimings.end": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "endTrunc": {
              "$dateTrunc": {
                "date": {"$first": "$batchTimings.end"},
                "unit": "day"
              }
            },
            "hoursToMilliseconds": {"$multiply": [60, 60, 1000]}
          },
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$endTrunc",
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  // enter end hour here
                  18,
                  "$$hoursToMilliseconds"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BljHcI5_nKI).